# Join two lists with a different amount of values to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip, generator

I have two lists of different lengths. One list has a fixed number of values that are to be used later as keys. The number of values in the second list can increase arbitrarily. The goal is to use the first list as a key for the second list again and again, depending on how many values list "a" gets.

```
d = ["a","b","c"]
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

In the end it should look like this:

```
c = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"a":4,"b":5,"c"=6,"a":7}
```

The keys from "d" are to be repeated again and again for the values in "a" as long as there are values in "d".
Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'cycle from itertools' [itertools - cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) module for you desired result. if you have two unequal length list.

```
from itertools import cycle 

d = ["a","b","c"]
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  
# zipping in cyclic if shorter length 
result = dict(zip(a, cycle(d))) 
  
# printing resultant dictionary 
print("resultant dictionary : ", str(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Karl Thornton a dictionary needs unique keys. You could do what Masud Morshed suggested, which is a good solution.

If your list `a` however is counting up constantly, you would not necessarily need a dictionary for this functionality. You could also write a function like this:

```
import string
def pseudo_dict(num):
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return alphabet[(num - 1)%4]

pseudo_dict(1) -> 'a'
```